# Preserve select option on re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am creating an interactive component with a set of options that can be disabled by a prop change.

```
export const ExportDialog = ({ recording, ... }: { recording: boolean, ... } ) => {
  const [recordingMethod, setRecordingMethod] = useState<string>("timeLimit");

  const changeMode = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => setRecordingMethod(event.target.value);

  ...

  return ( <>
    { !recording &&
      <select id="export-method-dropdown" disabled={disableOpts} onChange={changeMode}>
        <option value="timeLimit">using a time limit</option>
        <option value="sampleCount">using a # of samples</option>
        <option value="fileSize">using a file size</option>
      </select>
    }
    ...
    {  /* conditional rendering based on the value of recordingMethod */ }
    ...
  </> )
}
```

When the content is re-rendered after being re-enabled, the second conditional rendering block returns to its previous state, since it is dictated by the value of `recordingMethod`. However, the `<select>` in the first block of conditional rendering returns to its default option (the first one) since its selected option is not stored in state. This causes incompatibility between the first and second conditional rendering blocks.

How can I cause the `<select>` to remember which option was selected when it gets destroyed and re-rendered?

Comment: just add `value={recordingMethod}` to select

Comment: @OlegWock Should have known, slipped my mind. Thanks